# Macro to put stuff in the appendix

Tags: macros, appendices

I am trying to write a macro to put proofs of theorem in and out of the appendix by setting a variable.

I know how to do the following: In the following example, when I set the variable appendixenabled to 1, the proofs goes to a new section (section 2). Also, if it is set to 0, then the proof is inline.

```
\documentclass{article}[11pt]

\usepackage{amsthm, amsmath}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage[appendix=append]{apxproof}
\usepackage{thmtools, mathtools, thm-restate}\newtheorem*{theorem*}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{fact}{Fact}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]
\newtheorem{theorem}[lemma]{Theorem}
\renewenvironment{proof}{\smallskip\noindent{\bf Proof:}}%
        {\hspace*{\fill}\par}


% =========================================================
%                       Appendix stuff
% =========================================================
\newcommand{\myproof}[4]{
% 1: name of the environment
% 2: command 
% 3: label  of the theorem
% 4: proof
    \begin{proof}
        #4  
    \end{proof}
}
\def\appendixenabled{1}
% Switch to 0 to make the proofs inline
\if\appendixenabled1
    \renewcommand{\myproof}[4]{
    The proof is provided in Appendix~\ref{sec:proofof#3}
    \section{Proof of #1~\ref{#3}}
        \label{sec:proofof#3}
        \begin{proof}
            #4  
        \end{proof}
    }
\fi
% =========================================================

\begin{document}
\section{One}

\begin{restatable}{theorem}{aaa}
    \label{thmLabel}
    This is a resettable theorem!
\end{restatable}



\myproof{Theorem}{aaa}{thmLabel}{This is the proof.}
\end{document}
```

Instead, I need to move proof to the end of the document in an appendix section. However, if I add toappendix environment (in package apxproof) as follows, I will get compilation error. Any idea?

```
\if\appendixenabled1
    \renewcommand{\myproof}[4]{
    \begin{toappendix}
        The proof is provided in Appendix~\ref{sec:proofof#3}
        \section{Proof of #1~\ref{#3}}
        \label{sec:proofof#3}
        \begin{proof}
            #4  
        \end{proof}
    \end{toappendix}
    }
\fi
```

The error:

```
! FancyVerb Error:
  Extraneous input `The proof is provided in Appendix~\ref {sec:proofofthmLabel} \section {Proof of Theorem~\ref {thmLabel}} \label {sec:proofofthmLabel} \begin {proof} This is the proof. \end {proof} \end {toappendix} \end{document}' between \begin{toappendix}[<key=value>] and line end
.
\FV@Error ...ncyVerb Error:^^J\space \space #1^^J}

l.52 ...hmLabel}{This is the proof.}\end{document}

This input will be discarded. Hit <return> to continue.

)
Runaway argument?
! File ended while scanning use of \FancyVerbGetLine.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> 

I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.

! Emergency stop.
<*>
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your given code snippets compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: I am not sure what it is. How should I be doing it?

Comment: Please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) starting with `\documentclass` and end it with `\end{document}` ...

Comment: I just edited my question.